# How to annotate lines like this in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

See example:

[image: Example]

I hope I don't need to manually assign the coordinators of the texts. If this is too complicated to achieve in ggplot2, what are the alternatives in R? Or maybe even not in R?

Comment: One could use [`ggrepel`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html) to produce something like this. A reproducible example would be more inviting for an actual answer.

Comment: Why not use default legends? Alternatives could be manually adding text to the final plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Axeman says, `ggrepel` is a decent option. Unfortunately it will only avoid overlap with other labels, and not the lines, so the solution isn't quite perfect.

```
library(ggplot2)
install.packages("ggrepel")
library(ggrepel)

set.seed(50)
d <- data.frame(y = c(rnorm(50), rnorm(50, 5), rnorm(50, 10)), 
    x = rep(seq(50), times = 3), 
    group = rep(LETTERS[seq(3)], each = 50))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, group = group, label = group)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_text_repel(data = d[d$x == sample(d$x, 1), ], size = 10)
```

Comment: I got error: "Error in zero_range(from) : x must be length 1 or 2"

Comment: You "got"? But you provided no data, so we have no idea "`<what>`" was done to "`<what>`". (And that is the basis for my downvote to the question.)

Comment: It's from the last part `geom_text_repel(data = d[d$x == sample(d$x, 1), ], size = 10)`

Comment: The above line works with `geom_text`, but not `geom_text_repel`. Not sure why.

Comment: I restarted RStudio and then it works. I have no idea what caused that.

Comment: Instead of `size=10`, do `nudge_x = 1,nudge_y = 1` will get closer. But it is still not what I want. Check the graph, "white" label smartly goes under the line.